# Windows 10 Boot Loader is neither found in BIOS nor in GRUB. Unable to boot on Windows

Tags: dual-boot

My desktop contains two SSDs and one hard drive. One SSD has been installed with Windows 10. The installation went fine and I found the entry "windows boot loader" in BIOS.

After installing Ubuntu 16.04 on the 2nd SSD, I ran the command "sudo update-grub", but grub has failed to detect windows installation. Strangely after grub updating, "Windows-boot-loader" entry has disappeared from BIOS, however "boot override" (under save & exit menu of BIOS) still shows "windows-boot-loader".

Now I could very well log into Ubuntu 16.04 but not on windows 10. i.e., my windows 10 has been missing simultaneously from both BIOS as well from GRUB.

I booted through USB Pen drive(windows installation), and went inside "windows SSD" through "repair" option and I found entire installation has been present and safe.

**Note**: both windows and Ubuntu have been installed in UEFI.

Right now I am unable to boot into Windows. I need help in restoring the missing windows boot entry. Thanks in advance.